# Any clue from the console output after a jvm crash?

Tags: java, jvm, crash-dumps, jvm-crash

Just after a brutal crash of java 8 rcp app i had the message bellow, i looked into the pid file but nothing conclusive.

Does the output console message bellow give any clue to identify the cause of the crash?

```
 # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.102-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  0x000000005a3004fa
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
    #
    # An error report file with more information is saved as:
    # C:\Users\Desktop\eclipse\hs_err_pid2388.log
    Compiled method (nm)  824447 8663     n 0       org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS::HeapAlloc (native)
     total in heap  [0x0000000004417490,0x0000000004417808] = 888
     relocation     [0x00000000044175b0,0x00000000044175f8] = 72
     main code      [0x0000000004417600,0x0000000004417800] = 512
     oops           [0x0000000004417800,0x0000000004417808] = 8
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
    #
```

and bellow the history of Garbage Collection and other details from the pid file, is there any obvious or suspicions event?

```
Heap:  par new generation   total 94592K, used 13799K [0x0000000700000000, 0x00000007066a0000, 0x0000000714cc0000)   eden space 84096K,   8% used [0x0000000700000000, 0x00000007006e2490, 0x0000000705220000)   from space 10496K,  64% used [0x0000000705c60000, 0x00000007062f79e0, 0x00000007066a0000)   to   space 10496K,   0% used [0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705c60000)  concurrent mark-sweep generation total 324024K, used 201417K [0x0000000714cc0000, 0x000000072892e000, 0x00000007c0000000)  Metaspace       used 150371K, capacity 165839K, committed 165976K, reserved 1191936K   class space    used 18545K, capacity 22644K, committed 22672K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x00000000124c0000,0x0000000012ad0000] byte_map_base: 0x000000000ecc0000

Marking Bits: (CMSBitMap*) 0x0000000002314478  Bits: [0x0000000013250000, 0x0000000015d1d000)

Mod Union Table: (CMSBitMap*) 0x0000000002314538  Bits: [0x0000000001cc0000, 0x0000000001d6b340)

Polling page: 0x0000000000440000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=83671Kb max_used=83671Kb free=162088Kb  bounds [0x00000000029a0000, 0x0000000007be0000, 0x00000000119a0000]  total_blobs=23005 nmethods=21421 adapters=1495  compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events): Event: 824.132 Thread 0x0000000018dac800 28876   !   3       java.awt.Container::clearMostRecentFocusOwnerOnHide (117 bytes) Event:
824.133 Thread 0x0000000018dac800 nmethod 28876 0x0000000007bc7f10 code [0x0000000007bc81a0, 0x0000000007bc9968] Event: 824.133 Thread 0x0000000018dac800 28878       3       sun.util.locale.provider.TimeZoneNameUtility::retrieveDisplayNamesImpl (205 bytes) Event: 824.135 Thread 0x0000000018dac800 nmethod 28878 0x0000000007bca450 code [0x0000000007bca760, 0x0000000007bcc5b8] Event: 824.135 Thread 0x0000000018dac800 28877       3       sun.util.locale.provider.TimeZoneNameUtility::retrieveDisplayName (32 bytes) Event: 824.135 Thread 0x0000000018dac800 nmethod 28877 0x0000000007bc4a10 code [0x0000000007bc4b80, 0x0000000007bc4ea8] Event: 824.176 Thread 0x0000000018dac800 28879       3       com.klg.jclass.chart.JCStyle::setChanged (17 bytes) Event: 824.176 Thread 0x0000000018dac800 nmethod 28879 0x0000000007bbf790 code [0x0000000007bbf900, 0x0000000007bbfae8] Event: 824.198 Thread 0x0000000018dac800 28880       3       org.jscience.physics.units.Unit::getTransform (205 bytes) Event:
824.200 Thread 0x0000000018dac800 nmethod 28880 0x0000000007bcd390 code [0x0000000007bcd7c0, 0x0000000007bd0198]

GC Heap History (10 events): Event: 807.831 GC heap before {Heap before GC invocations=124 (full 6):  par new generation   total 94592K, used 90429K [0x0000000700000000, 0x00000007066a0000, 0x0000000714cc0000)   eden space 84096K, 100% used [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705220000)   from space 10496K,  60% used [0x0000000705220000, 0x000000070584f688, 0x0000000705c60000)   to   space 10496K,   0% used [0x0000000705c60000, 0x0000000705c60000, 0x00000007066a0000)  concurrent mark-sweep generation total 270020K, used 247786K [0x0000000714cc0000, 0x0000000725471000, 0x00000007c0000000)  Metaspace       used 149979K, capacity 165215K, committed 165464K, reserved 1191936K   class space    used 18533K, capacity 22636K, committed 22672K, reserved 1048576K Event: 807.840 GC heap after Heap after GC invocations=125 (full 6):  par new generation   total 94592K, used 8645K [0x0000000700000000, 0x00000007066a0000, 0x0000000714cc0000)   eden space 84096K,   0% used [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000705220000)   from space 10496K,  82% used [0x0000000705c60000, 0x00000007064d1448, 0x00000007066a0000)   to   space 10496K,   0% used [0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705c60000)  concurrent mark-sweep generation total 270020K, used 248545K [0x0000000714cc0000, 0x0000000725471000, 0x00000007c0000000)  Metaspace       used 149979K, capacity 165215K, committed 165464K, reserved 1191936K   class space    used 18533K, capacity 22636K, committed 22672K, reserved 1048576K } Event: 813.547 GC heap before {Heap before GC invocations=125 (full 7):  par new generation   total 94592K, used 92741K [0x0000000700000000, 0x00000007066a0000, 0x0000000714cc0000)   eden space 84096K, 100% used [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705220000)   from space 10496K,  82% used [0x0000000705c60000, 0x00000007064d1448, 0x00000007066a0000)   to   space 10496K,   0% used [0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705c60000)  concurrent mark-sweep generation total 324024K, used 194412K [0x0000000714cc0000, 0x000000072892e000, 0x00000007c0000000)  Metaspace       used 150128K, capacity 165443K, committed 165720K, reserved 1191936K   class space    used 18536K, capacity 22642K, committed 22672K, reserved 1048576K Event: 813.556 GC heap after Heap after GC invocations=126 (full 7):  par new generation   total 94592K, used 10496K [0x0000000700000000, 0x00000007066a0000, 0x0000000714cc0000)   eden space 84096K,   0% used [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000705220000)   from space 10496K, 100% used [0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705c60000, 0x0000000705c60000)   to   space 10496K,   0% used [0x0000000705c60000, 0x0000000705c60000, 0x00000007066a0000)  concurrent mark-sweep generation total 324024K, used 195226K [0x0000000714cc0000, 0x000000072892e000, 0x00000007c0000000)  Metaspace       used 150128K, capacity 165443K, committed 165720K, reserved 1191936K   class space    used 18536K, capacity 22642K, committed 22672K, reserved 1048576K } Event: 818.730 GC heap before {Heap before GC invocations=126 (full 7):  par new generation   total 94592K, used 94592K [0x0000000700000000, 0x00000007066a0000, 0x0000000714cc0000)   eden space 84096K, 100% used [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705220000)   from space 10496K, 100% used [0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705c60000, 0x0000000705c60000)   to   space 10496K,   0% used [0x0000000705c60000, 0x0000000705c60000, 0x00000007066a0000)  concurrent mark-sweep generation total 324024K, used 195226K [0x0000000714cc0000, 0x000000072892e000, 0x00000007c0000000)  Metaspace       used 150229K, capacity 165635K, committed 165720K, reserved 1191936K   class space    used 18543K, capacity 22642K, committed 22672K, reserved 1048576K Event: 818.745 GC heap after Heap after GC invocations=127 (full 7):  par new generation   total 94592K, used 9407K [0x0000000700000000, 0x00000007066a0000, 0x0000000714cc0000)   eden space 84096K,   0% used [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000705220000)   from space 10496K,  89% used [0x0000000705c60000, 0x000000070658fec0, 0x00000007066a0000)   to   space 10496K,   0% used [0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705c60000)  concurrent mark-sweep generation total 324024K, used 199782K [0x0000000714cc0000, 0x000000072892e000, 0x00000007c0000000)  Metaspace       used 150229K, capacity 165635K, committed 165720K, reserved 1191936K   class space    used 18543K, capacity 22642K, committed 22672K, reserved 1048576K } Event: 821.350 GC heap before {Heap before GC invocations=127 (full 7):  par new generation   total 94592K, used 93503K [0x0000000700000000, 0x00000007066a0000, 0x0000000714cc0000)   eden space 84096K, 100% used [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705220000)   from space 10496K,  89% used [0x0000000705c60000, 0x000000070658fec0, 0x00000007066a0000)   to   space 10496K,   0% used [0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705c60000)  concurrent mark-sweep generation total 324024K, used 199782K [0x0000000714cc0000, 0x000000072892e000, 0x00000007c0000000)  Metaspace       used 150301K, capacity 165763K, committed 165976K, reserved 1191936K   class space    used 18544K, capacity 22642K, committed 22672K, reserved 1048576K Event: 821.359 GC heap after Heap after GC invocations=128 (full 7):  par new generation   total 94592K, used 6812K [0x0000000700000000, 0x00000007066a0000, 0x0000000714cc0000)   eden space 84096K,   0% used [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000705220000)   from space 10496K,  64% used [0x0000000705220000, 0x00000007058c7280, 0x0000000705c60000)   to   space 10496K,   0% used [0x0000000705c60000, 0x0000000705c60000, 0x00000007066a0000)  concurrent mark-sweep generation total 324024K, used 199782K [0x0000000714cc0000, 0x000000072892e000, 0x00000007c0000000)  Metaspace       used 150301K, capacity 165763K, committed 165976K, reserved 1191936K   class space    used 18544K, capacity 22642K, committed 22672K, reserved 1048576K } Event: 823.902 GC heap before {Heap before GC invocations=128 (full 7):  par new generation   total 94592K, used 90908K [0x0000000700000000, 0x00000007066a0000, 0x0000000714cc0000)   eden space 84096K, 100% used [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705220000)   from space 10496K,  64% used [0x0000000705220000, 0x00000007058c7280, 0x0000000705c60000)   to   space 10496K,   0% used [0x0000000705c60000, 0x0000000705c60000, 0x00000007066a0000)  concurrent mark-sweep generation total 324024K, used 199782K [0x0000000714cc0000, 0x000000072892e000, 0x00000007c0000000)  Metaspace       used 150360K, capacity 165839K, committed 165976K, reserved 1191936K   class space    used 18545K, capacity 22644K, committed 22672K, reserved 1048576K Event: 823.911 GC heap after Heap after GC invocations=129 (full 7):  par new generation   total 94592K, used 6750K [0x0000000700000000, 0x00000007066a0000, 0x0000000714cc0000)   eden space 84096K,   0% used [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000705220000)   from space 10496K,  64% used [0x0000000705c60000, 0x00000007062f79e0, 0x00000007066a0000)   to   space 10496K,   0% used [0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705220000, 0x0000000705c60000)  concurrent mark-sweep generation total 324024K, used 201417K [0x0000000714cc0000, 0x000000072892e000, 0x00000007c0000000)  Metaspace       used 150360K, capacity 165839K, committed 165976K, reserved 1191936K   class space    used 18545K, capacity 22644K, committed 22672K, reserved 1048576K }

Deoptimization events (10 events): Event: 822.271 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00000000034d9238 method=java.lang.Class.getMethod(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Method; @ 61 Event: 822.271 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00000000034d9238 method=java.lang.Class.getMethod(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Method; @ 61 Event: 822.271 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00000000034d9238 method=java.lang.Class.getMethod(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Method; @ 61 Event: 822.438 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00000000039b2068 method=org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/lang/Class; @ 127 Event: 822.532 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00000000039b2068 method=org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/lang/Class; @ 127 Event: 822.534 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00000000039b2068 method=org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/lang/Class; @ 127 Event: 822.536 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00000000039b2068 method=org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/lang/Class; @ 127 Event: 822.537 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00000000039b2068 method=org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/lang/Class; @ 127 Event: 822.539 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00000000039b2068 method=org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/lang/Class; @ 127 Event: 822.547 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00000000039b2068 method=org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/lang/Class; @ 127

Internal exceptions (10 events): Event: 788.016 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Implicit null exception at 0x000000000691bb5d to 0x000000000691bd81 Event: 789.196 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Implicit null exception at 0x00000000045b3bf8 to 0x00000000045b5d7d Event:
789.466 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000002be87d3 to 0x0000000002be88c5 Event: 790.315 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000006b095b4 to 0x0000000006b0a5dd Event: 790.336 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000002b6a929 to 0x0000000002b6aa10 Event:
806.346 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Implicit null exception at 0x00000000047b464e to 0x00000000047bc63d Event: 806.368 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000004ed19c6 to 0x0000000004edf009 Event: 817.328 Thread 0x0000000022a30000 Exception <a 'java/net/ConnectException': Connection refused: connect> (0x0000000701640640) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u102\7268\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735] Event: 818.693 Thread 0x00000000022b8800 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000004d5a9d4 to 0x0000000004d5ab26 Event: 821.145 Thread 0x000000001b0fa000 Exception <a 'java/lang/InterruptedException': sleep interrupted> (0x00000007037b5bd8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u102\7268\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 3215]

Events (10 events): Event: 823.709 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done Event: 823.853 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias Event: 823.853 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done Event: 823.901 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation Event: 823.911 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation done Event: 824.021 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias Event: 824.022 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done Event: 824.054 Thread 0x000000001d5b4800 Thread added: 0x000000001d5b4800 Event: 824.176 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias Event: 824.176 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done


Dynamic libraries: 0x000000013fb40000 - 0x000000013fb77000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\javaw.exe 0x00000000777b0000 - 0x000000007795a000    C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll 0x0000000077690000 - 0x00000000777af000   C:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll 0x000007fefd5d0000 - 0x000007fefd63a000    C:\windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll 0x000007feff8e0000 - 0x000007feff9bb000  C:\windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll 0x000007feff570000 - 0x000007feff60f000    C:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll 0x000007feff640000 - 0x000007feff65f000  C:\windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll 0x000007fefef00000
- 0x000007feff02d000    C:\windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll 0x0000000077590000 - 0x000000007768a000  C:\windows\system32\USER32.dll 0x000007feff2b0000 - 0x000007feff317000  C:\windows\system32\GDI32.dll 0x000007fefeed0000 - 0x000007fefeede000   C:\windows\system32\LPK.dll 0x000007fefd8b0000 - 0x000007fefd97a000     C:\windows\system32\USP10.dll 0x000007fefb710000 - 0x000007fefb904000   C:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_fa3b1e3d17594757\COMCTL32.dll 0x000007feffa40000 - 0x000007feffab1000    C:\windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll 0x000007feff610000 - 0x000007feff63e000     C:\windows\system32\IMM32.DLL 0x000007feff380000 - 0x000007feff489000   C:\windows\system32\MSCTF.dll 0x0000000075230000 - 0x0000000075269000   C:\PROGRA~2\Sophos\SOPHOS~1\SOPHOS~2.DLL 0x0000000077980000 - 0x0000000077987000    C:\windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL 0x00000000648b0000 - 0x0000000064981000   C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\msvcr100.dll 0x00000000619f0000 - 0x000000006228a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\server\jvm.dll 0x000007fef91c0000 - 0x000007fef91c9000   C:\windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll 0x000007feff030000
- 0x000007feff07d000    C:\windows\system32\WS2_32.dll 0x000007fefd8a0000 - 0x000007fefd8a8000  C:\windows\system32\NSI.dll 0x000007fefaf10000 - 0x000007fefaf4b000     C:\windows\system32\WINMM.dll 0x000007fefc720000 - 0x000007fefc72c000   C:\windows\system32\VERSION.dll 0x00000000660d0000 - 0x00000000660df000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\verify.dll 0x0000000064c60000 - 0x0000000064c89000   C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\java.dll 0x0000000064c20000 - 0x0000000064c55000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\jdwp.dll 0x0000000064c10000 - 0x0000000064c18000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\npt.dll 0x0000000064bf0000 - 0x0000000064c06000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\zip.dll 0x000007fefe140000 - 0x000007fefeec9000  C:\windows\system32\SHELL32.dll 0x000007fefdc60000 - 0x000007fefde63000     C:\windows\system32\ole32.dll 0x000007fefd4f0000 - 0x000007fefd4ff000   C:\windows\system32\profapi.dll 0x00000000648a0000
- 0x00000000648a9000    C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\dt_socket.dll 0x000007fefb2d0000 - 0x000007fefb2e5000    C:\windows\system32\NLAapi.dll 0x000007fef9850000
- 0x000007fef9865000    C:\windows\system32\napinsp.dll 0x000007fef9830000 - 0x000007fef9849000     C:\windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll 0x000007fefcc80000 - 0x000007fefccd5000     C:\windows\System32\mswsock.dll 0x000007fefcb00000
- 0x000007fefcb5b000    C:\windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll 0x000007fef9870000 - 0x000007fef987b000  C:\windows\System32\winrnr.dll 0x000007fefbe60000 - 0x000007fefbe87000  C:\windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL 0x000007fefc310000 - 0x000007fefc31b000    C:\windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL 0x000007fef9cf0000 - 0x000007fef9d43000  C:\windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll 0x000007fef9880000 - 0x000007fef9888000    C:\windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll 0x000007fefc320000 - 0x000007fefc350000    C:\ProgramData\Sophos\Web Intelligence\swi_ifslsp_64.dll 0x000007fefc300000 - 0x000007fefc307000    C:\windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll 0x000007fefcd20000 - 0x000007fefcd38000    C:\windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll 0x000007fefc9e0000
- 0x000007fefca27000    C:\windows\system32\rsaenh.dll 0x000007fefd5a0000 - 0x000007fefd5be000  C:\windows\system32\USERENV.dll 0x000007fefd380000 - 0x000007fefd38f000     C:\windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll 0x0000000064880000 - 0x000000006489a000   C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\net.dll 0x000007fefcc70000 - 0x000007fefcc77000  C:\windows\System32\wship6.dll 0x000007fef9da0000
- 0x000007fef9db1000    C:\windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL 0x000007fef9d80000 - 0x000007fef9d98000   C:\windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL 0x0000000064860000 - 0x0000000064871000    C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\nio.dll 0x0000000072000000 - 0x0000000072012000  C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316\eclipse_1608.dll 0x000007fefbc30000 - 0x000007fefbc86000   C:\windows\system32\uxtheme.dll 0x000007fef2b20000 - 0x000007fef2d98000     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\nview\nview64.dll 0x000007fefa440000 - 0x000007fefa447000   C:\windows\system32\MSIMG32.dll 0x000007fefc730000 - 0x000007fefc741000     C:\windows\system32\WTSAPI32.dll 0x000007feff490000 - 0x000007feff56a000    C:\windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll 0x000007fefbbf0000 - 0x000007fefbc1c000    C:\windows\system32\POWRPROF.dll 0x000007feff660000 - 0x000007feff837000    C:\windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll 0x000007fefd560000 - 0x000007fefd596000    C:\windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll 0x000007fefd510000 - 0x000007fefd52a000    C:\windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll 0x000007fefc210000 - 0x000007fefc23d000  C:\windows\system32\ntmarta.dll 0x000007feff320000
- 0x000007feff372000    C:\windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll 0x0000000070f30000 - 0x0000000070f7e000     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\nview\NVWRSFR.DLL 0x000007feff840000 - 0x000007feff8d9000   C:\windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL 0x0000000019ca0000 - 0x0000000019d48000     C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\OpenFlowSuite_Win64\org.eclipse.osgi\664\0\.cp\swt-win32-4430.dll 0x000007feff080000 - 0x000007feff117000  C:\windows\system32\comdlg32.dll 0x000007fef9eb0000 - 0x000007fef9f21000    C:\windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV 0x000007fefd980000 - 0x000007fefdc52000    C:\windows\system32\WININET.dll 0x000007fefd500000 - 0x000007fefd504000     C:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll 0x000007fefd530000 - 0x000007fefd534000  C:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll 0x000007fefd640000 - 0x000007fefd644000     C:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-version-l1-1-0.dll 0x000007fefd550000 - 0x000007fefd553000     C:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-normaliz-l1-1-0.dll 0x0000000077970000 - 0x0000000077973000    C:\windows\system32\normaliz.DLL 0x000007fefde70000 - 0x000007fefe13a000    C:\windows\system32\iertutil.dll 0x000007fefd540000 - 0x000007fefd545000    C:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll 0x000007fefd650000 - 0x000007fefd7bd000    C:\windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll 0x000007fefd4e0000 - 0x000007fefd4ef000     C:\windows\system32\MSASN1.dll 0x000007fefae20000
- 0x000007fefae38000    C:\windows\system32\dwmapi.dll 0x000007fefb910000 - 0x000007fefba3c000  C:\windows\system32\propsys.dll 0x0000000002620000 - 0x000000000263e000     C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\OpenFlowSuite_Win64\org.eclipse.osgi\664\0\.cp\swt-gdip-win32-4430.dll 0x000007fefb050000 - 0x000007fefb266000     C:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.23545_none_14599ab28b920323\gdiplus.dll 0x000000006d650000 - 0x000000006d7e8000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\awt.dll 0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000180012000  C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\OpenFlowSuite_Win64\org.eclipse.osgi\549\0\.cp\os\win32\x86_64\localfile_1_0_0.dll 0x000007fefac70000 - 0x000007fefadd1000     C:\windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll 0x0000000070800000 - 0x00000000708d2000   C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\msvcr100.dll 0x00000000725a0000 - 0x0000000072638000   C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\msvcp100.dll 0x0000000070ef0000 - 0x0000000070f01000   C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\vcomp100.dll 0x000007feec250000 - 0x000007feec377000   C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\InventorBase.dll 0x000007fef9270000 - 0x000007fef9395000   C:\windows\system32\dbghelp.dll 0x000007feec3b0000 - 0x000007feec4a7000     C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\InventorGL.dll 0x000007fef29f0000 - 0x000007fef2a1d000     C:\windows\system32\GLU32.dll 0x000007fee8b10000 - 0x000007fee8c2d000   C:\windows\system32\OPENGL32.dll 0x000007fee8a10000 - 0x000007fee8b01000    C:\windows\system32\DDRAW.dll 0x000007fef50e0000 - 0x000007fef50e8000   C:\windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll 0x000007fee88f0000 - 0x000007fee8a0e000    C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\InventorImage.dll 0x000007fef3fd0000 - 0x000007fef3fef000  C:\windows\system32\AVIFIL32.dll 0x000007fef2e50000 - 0x000007fef2e68000    C:\windows\system32\MSACM32.dll 0x000007fef2aa0000
- 0x000007fef2ac9000    C:\windows\system32\MSVFW32.dll 0x000007fef29d0000 - 0x000007fef29e7000     C:\windows\system32\AVICAP32.dll 0x000007fee7e70000 - 0x000007fee88ec000    C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\fei.ImageAccess.dll 0x000007fefeee0000 - 0x000007fefeef9000    C:\windows\system32\imagehlp.dll 0x000007fee7140000 - 0x000007fee7e6c000    C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\Inventor.dll 0x000007feea5e0000 - 0x000007feea641000   C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\complex1.6.dll 0x000007fee7030000 - 0x000007fee713b000     C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\ScaleViz.dll 0x000007fee6c60000 - 0x000007fee7024000   C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\MeshViz.dll 0x000007feed160000 - 0x000007feed1c5000    C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\HardCopy.dll 0x000007fef2850000 - 0x000007fef287f000   C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\InventorAlgorithms.dll 0x000007fee6a40000 - 0x000007fee6c5b000     C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\LDM.dll 0x000007fee67c0000 - 0x000007fee6a37000    C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\VolumeViz.dll 0x000007fee66c0000 - 0x000007fee67b5000  C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\TerrainViz.dll 0x000007feec200000 - 0x000007feec243000     C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\DirectViz.dll 0x000007feea2c0000 - 0x000007feea330000  C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\SolidViz.dll 0x000007fef16b0000 - 0x000007fef16d8000   C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\FXViz.dll 0x000007fee6630000 - 0x000007fee66b6000  C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\ScaleVizRemote.dll 0x000007feeedc0000 - 0x000007feeedd6000     C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\IvDLZlib.dll 0x000007fee6240000 - 0x000007fee6621000   C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\RemoteVizServices.dll 0x000007fee61d0000 - 0x000007fee623d000  C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\InventorGui.dll 0x000007fee60b0000 - 0x000007fee61ca000    C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\InventorWin.dll 0x000007feeed50000 - 0x000007feeed8c000    C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\MeshVizWin.dll 0x000000006d3d0000 - 0x000000006d64d000     C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\QtCore4.dll 0x000000006caa0000 - 0x000000006d3cf000    C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\QtGui4.dll 0x000000006c9f0000 - 0x000000006ca9e000     C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\QtOpenGL4.dll 0x0000000070790000 - 0x00000000707f7000  C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\OpenFlowPlatform\Bundles\com.openinventor.win64\QtXml4.dll

VM Arguments: jvm_args:
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:58474 -Xms307m -Xmx3071m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252  java_command: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main -launcher C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool\eclipse.exe -name Eclipse -showsplash 600 -product fr.ifp.openflowsuite.welcome.OFSFeature -data C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017/../runtime-OpenFlowSuiteProduct.product
-configuration file:C:/Users/zaraidi/Desktop/Workspace_Anas_2017/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/OpenFlowSuite_Win64/
-dev file:C:/Users/zaraidi/Desktop/Workspace_Anas_2017/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/OpenFlowSuite_Win64/dev.properties
-os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -nl en_GB -consoleLog java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\zaraidi\Desktop\Workspace_Anas_2017\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD
```

Comment: Open `C:\Users\Desktop\eclipse\hs_err_pid2388.log` file

Answer (score 1):

There is native crash indicated by the problematic frame

## Problematic frame:

```
# C  0x000000005a3004fa
```

More details about the crash can be found in hs_error file which is generated in the location C:\Users\Desktop\eclipse\hs_err_pid2388.log
Regarding how the hs_error file will be structured and how it can be used for decoding information can be found here - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/crashes-137240.html#gbyzj